# read string as a file using io.StringIO

Tags: python, file, io, package, stringio

I need to make a string to be read by `bibtexparser`'s `parsing_read`. As far as I understood the module, it only reads file, not stream, so I have done:

```
text = "Some text"
with open("/tmp/bibtmp.bib", "w") as bibfile:
    bibfile.write(text)
self.parsing.parsing_read("/tmp/bibtmp.bib")
```

But, I am trying to  make it read the string, and trying `io.StringIO` module as:

```
fakefile = io.StringIO("SomeText")
self.parsing.parsing_read(fakefile)
```

which is giving error(from the self.parsing.parsing_read, which opens the file):

```
TypeError: invalid file: <_io.StringIO object at 0x7fb4d6537ca8>
```

So, obviously, fakefile is `io.StringIO`, and not a `Fake`file.

Am I understanding `io.StringIO`'s purpose wrong? or just doing it wrong?

Comment: A tempfile might be more suitable https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html, you have the .name attibute with a NamedTemporaryFile

Comment: What do you suppose to be a "fake" file?  Either an object *is* a file, or it is not (it can be file-like, e.g., stream). From the [dox](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html), the `io.StringIO` class provides *An in-memory stream for unicode text.*

Comment: You might also want to link to the docs containing `parsing_read`

Comment: Yes, please link to dox for the `parsing_read`, which are not found [here](https://bibtexparser.readthedocs.org/en/v0.6.2/bibtexparser.html)....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation from bibtexparser class, I think you should be using the `.loads` method, which returns a `BibDatabase` object from an input *string or unicode*.  (This differs from the `load` method which does require a file object)

https://bibtexparser.readthedocs.org/en/v0.6.2/_modules/bibtexparser.html#loads

> `bibtexparser.loads(bibtex_str, parser=None)`
>
> Load BibDatabase object from a string
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - bibtex_str (str or unicode) – input BibTeX string to be parsed
> - parser (BibTexParser) – custom parser to use (optional)
>
> **Returns:**
>
> - bibliographic database object
>
> **Return type:**
>
> - BibDatabase